# How to integrate auto fill for other apps in my flutter password manager?

Tags: flutter, passwords, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, password-autofill

This is my password manager. I stored many passwords in it. when i open other apps for login, my password manager should suggest me for auto fill credentials. If I stored Facebook password in my flutter password manager and when i open Facebook on mobile app or web my password manager should suggest me for the username and password auto fill.

How can we do auto fill credentials suggestion for other apps from flutter app?